# How to resolve "Your search cannot be completed because no Search service is available. Contact your administrator for more information."?

Tags: search, 2016, farm-solution, ssom, result-source

I am working with SP2016 Farm solution.

I have configured a Search Service on my farm, customized the result source too. When I use the result source in Content Search WebPart on SharePoint Page, it gives me the result.

While I try to get the search result from the SSOM C# code, I get error

> Your search cannot be completed because no Search service is
>   available. Contact your administrator for more information.

I am using following set of code

```
SPSite currentSite = SPContext.Current.Site;
SearchQueryAndSiteSettingsServiceProxy settingsProxy = SPFarm.Local.ServiceProxies.GetValue<SearchQueryAndSiteSettingsServiceProxy>();
SearchServiceApplicationProxy searchProxy = settingsProxy.ApplicationProxies.GetValue<SearchServiceApplicationProxy>("SEARCH SERVICE NAME");
SearchObjectOwner serviceApplicationOwner = new SearchObjectOwner(SearchObjectLevel.Ssa);
SourceRecord serviceApplicationResultSourceMedia = searchProxy.GetResultSourceByName("SEARCH RESULT SOURCE NAME", serviceApplicationOwner);
```

Till this the code works fine,

Now I am trying to use `KeyWordQuery` class to get the data from Search Result Source,

```
KeywordQuery query = new KeywordQuery("CURRENT SITE OBJECT");
```

I get the error

> Your search cannot be completed because no Search service is
>   available. Contact your administrator for more information.

Can anyone suggest me what I am missing?

Comment: Make sure you have used **Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query** namespace

Comment: Thanks @MohamedEl-QassasMVP, I too found the same reference. :-)

Comment: Glad to hear bro :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Add the `Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query` reference to your solution
- Then in your code behind, use this reference as the following

> using Microsoft.SharePoint;
>   **using Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query;**